# How to set padding on menu icon in action bar on API Level 9 and 9+?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles, android-menu

I want to add two menu icon in action bar, but there's some extra space taken between them, and in this case, the app name not shown fully and also looking not good...

How can I omit these extra space around icons by setting padding or other way?

Comment: Honest question-  why support 9?  Less than .1% of downloads from the playstore last month were version 9, and only .2% were version 8 or lower.  See http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html  You're better off not spending the time/effort on such a low usage amount and moving to a minimum supported version of 10 or 15.

Comment: Good support, Thank you..... but my client want it... what should i do for him?